With rust bindgen how can I allowlist variants of an unnamed enum
I have a C++ header file for which im trying to use bindgen to generate rust bindings. I have it working however when I've tried to add allowlists im struggling on how to include variants of an anonymous enum in the header file. They generate fine when I dont use any allowlists, but the compile time is increased
Header file
enum {
    xplmType_Unknown                         = 0,
    xplmType_Int                             = 1,
    xplmType_Float                           = 2,
    xplmType_Double                          = 4,
    xplmType_FloatArray                      = 8,
    xplmType_IntArray                        = 16,
    xplmType_Data                            = 32,
};

I have tried using variations of an allowlist to try to get it to include. I've tried with allowlist_item, aswell as allowlist_type
My allowlist
.allowlist_item("xplmType_Unknown")
.allowlist_item("XPLM.*")
.allowlist_item("xplm.*")

xplmType_unknown, and others in the enum, never are included in the output
